# Non-uniform polarization

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

I'm trying to understand this concept for a few days now to no avail. Consider some polarized ball with radius $R$:

[image]

The polarization is nonuniform, for the sake of example say $\vec{P} = (R-r) \hat{z}$ becuase I want it to vanish at the shell. I drew some of it on the ball.

I can't seem to figure out the electric field inside in such situations, as Gauss law doesn't help. I tried many things, but it seems I have a big misunderstanding and I can't seem to figure out what to do. Outside I can consider two non-uniformly charges balls distanced a small $d$ that act as a big dipole, but what about inside? How does one find the electric potential in such situations? Do the outer shells generally contribute to the potential inside some $r<R$ ball or not?

**Just clarifying this is not a specific homework question I want a solution to but a general concept I can't seem to figure out.**